# Save image file Uri error saving null pointer exception

Tags: android, save, uri

I'm trying to save my edited image but I keep getting null pointer exception error. here is my OnClick save button. The image I'm fetching is inside a drawView and framelayout.

```
 public void save(View v) {

    String name = mImageName;
    if (name.indexOf(".") > 0) {
        name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")) + "_e";
    }
    MediaStoreSaver.save(mImage2,
            mImagePath,
            name,
            this,
            MediaStoreSaver.TYPE_JPG);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And here is my MediaStoreSave Class. Any idea what I did wrong?

```
public class MediaStoreSaver {
    public static final byte TYPE_PNG = 2;
    public static final byte TYPE_JPG = 3;
public static final String save(Bitmap bitmap,
                                String folderName,
                                String imageName,
                                Context mContext,
                                byte imageType) {
    File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String folder_path = folder.getAbsolutePath();
    String file_path = folder_path + "/" + folderName;
    File dir = new File(file_path);

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = null;
    try {
        String suffix = ".png";
        Bitmap.CompressFormat format = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG;
        if (imageType == TYPE_JPG) {
            suffix = ".jpg";
            format = Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;
        }

        file = File.createTempFile(imageName, suffix, dir);
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(format, 100, fOut);
        System.out.println("saved image: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MediaStorageScan(mContext, file);
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}

/*
 * Refresh image files to view them on computer
 */
private static void MediaStorageScan(Context context, final File file) {
    final Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE", fileUri));
    }

    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE", fileUri));

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(fileUri);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

}
```

Here is my logcat message:

> 2019-02-28 16:38:59.512 15830-15830/rs.example.android.com.healingbrush E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: rs.example.android.com.healingbrush, PID: 15830
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4827) 
>     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5773)
>     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23035)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4822)
>     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5773) 
>     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23035) 
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) v
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802)
>  
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
>  
>     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
>     at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:452)
>     at rs.example.android.com.healingbrush.MediaStoreSaver.MediaStorageScan(MediaStoreSaver.java:77)
>     at rs.example.android.com.healingbrush.MediaStoreSaver.save(MediaStoreSaver.java:69)
>     at rs.example.android.com.healingbrush.MainActivity.save(MainActivity.java:342)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4822) 
>     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5773) 
>     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23035) 
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802)
>  
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
>     2019-02-28 16:38:59.578 1332-1443/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'cd07d33 rs.example.android.com.healingbrush/rs.example.android.com.healingbrush.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>     2019-02-28 16:39:01.733 2583-6309/? E/resmon: [34: StackTraceElement.run] waiting for trigger

Comment: `String name = mImageName;` - where did you define `mImageName`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: do you see any other messages produced by `e.printStackTrace();` in logcat?